# How to use if-else statement in Standard Bigquery?

Tags: sql, database, google-bigquery

If I have a table like the following:

```
|**Entry**-------**Name**--------**Date**------------------**Boolean**|    
|  1.-----------Car-----------2019-12-01----------True|  
|  2.-----------Car-----------2019-12-03----------False|  
|  3.-----------Bus-----------2019-12-05----------False|  
|  4.-----------Bus-----------2019-12-11----------False|
```

I want to select a row with distinct **Name** if **Boolean** column is true, or if the boolean values are false then select the row with earliest date. So for the **car** entry I want to select the first row since the boolean for it is true (so I can ignore all other entries) and for the **bus** entry I want to select the last row since both the booleans for it are false so I want to pick the earliest date (closest to present date).

Edit: Expected output

|  1.-----------Car-----------2019-12-01----------True|
|  4.-----------Bus-----------2019-12-11----------False|

Comment: Please add more data like your current output and expected output.

Comment: what if there were yet another row for Car with TRUE - which row you would select?

Comment: There are two parts of your query, so you can write query for both case separately and union them. Because writing as single query with 'CASE WHEN ...THEN.. ' with each column is more Complex for both reader and writer.

Comment: There can only be one row with car and true. So that's why the moment we read a row with true we select that. If it doesn't have true then we look at the date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY bool DESC, dt DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY name
```

Note; this is based on "There can only be one row with car and true" from your comment ...

if to apply to sample data from your question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Car' name, '2019-12-01' dt, TRUE bool UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Car', '2019-12-03', FALSE UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bus', '2019-12-05', FALSE UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Bus', '2019-12-11', FALSE 
)
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY bool DESC, dt DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)]
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY name
```

result is

```
Row name    dt          bool     
1   Car     2019-12-01  true     
2   Bus     2019-12-11  false
```